# Trying to install gdal 3.0.4 on Red Hat 8

Tags: jpeg, redhat, gdal, libjpeg, jpeg2000

I'm running Red Hat 8, and I'm trying to install gdal 3.0.4 on it.

The commands I've excuted thus far:

```sh
wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/3.0.4/gdal-3.0.4.tar.gz
tar zxvf gdal-3.0.4.tar.gz
cd gdal-3.0.4
./configure
sudo make install
```

After I run `sudo make install`, I get the following error messages:

```sh
path/to/gdal-3.0.4/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress_12`
path/to/gdal-3.0.4/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_write_tables_12`
path/to/gdal-3.0.4/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress_12`
```

...

It continues on like this for some amount of lines all starting with `jpeg` and ending with `12` and different words in between. It finally ends with:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [GNUmakefile:82: gdalinfo] Error 1
make: *** [GNUmakefile:112: apps-target] Error 2
```

I'm not sure what to do or what this error even means. If anyone has any ideas, or if there is anymore information I can share, let me know.

Comment: Did you have included OpenMPI library?

Comment: I'm not sure. How would I check? What does the OpenMPI library have to do with gdal and jpeg?

Comment: When you check github page you will find similar issue, resolved by adding this library

Comment: Can you link to the github page/issue?

Comment: My mistake, was different one. Sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running my commands, if you run

```sh
sudo make clean
 ./configure --with-libtiff=internal --with-geotiff=internal --with-jpeg=internal --with-jpeg12
sudo make install
```

Then my error cleared up. Of course, I suspect one would need the right libjpeg packages installed as well. I may have had them installed beforehand so it's something to keep in mind.

https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/TIFF12BitJPEG

The above link was extremely useful in solving this issue.